# Is the dialog in the One Piece opening unique?

Tags: one-piece

In the latests one piece opening (opening 17 Wake Up) At around the 1:27 mark of the opening there is a short dialogue between Blackbeard and Luffy, with our Straw Hat hero telling Blackbeard it is him who will obtain One Piece and be the Pirate King!

Is this a unique feature made by One Piece just like their long openings instead of openings and endings. Or has it been used before/ is it more common to add a piece of dialog in between the opening of a series.

Comment: "Or has it been used before" you mean is this dialog happen in anime or manga before? or something else? I haven't watch the anime but I'm pretty sure that Luffy said that to Kurohige somewhere in manga. (He did say that to a lot people)

Comment: @ShinobuOshino I mean as in the style, half way the opening a sudden dialog part. I do see it sometimes during endings of series, that in the final ending song there is a piece of dialog. But never before in a opening. So I wonderd, is this something one piece unique. Did they create it, or has it happend before in another anime.

Comment: don't remember seeing anywhere else. maybe unique to OP. but can't say I've seen much anime to verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unique in this opening

There hasn't been any opening before with text between two characters. I've seen every opening and haven't seen it in earlier openings, that being said I don't know every ending of OP so I don't know if it was used in those before.

The piece of dialogue is just flavor, nothing more nothing less. It isn't shown anywhere in the anime or the manga. This is probably just to spice up the opening and set a premice for the opening battle that follows suit.

If any other anime did this please let me know or correct me but I haven't seen it anywhere before, but I haven't seen every anime so I can't say